# Custom MarkerStyles possible in C#-WPF Chart control

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I'm pretty new in C#. working with charts and trying to remove the Markers from my plotted lineseries.

here is the line of codes:

```
private void LoadLineChartData()
    {
        LineSeries ls1 = new LineSeries();
        ls1.Title = "Title1";
        ls1.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key");
        ls1.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value");

        ls1.ItemsSource =
                    new KeyValuePair<int, int>[]{
    new KeyValuePair<int,int>(1, 100),
    new KeyValuePair<int,int>(2, 130),
    new KeyValuePair<int,int>(3, 150),
    new KeyValuePair<int,int>(4, 125),
    new KeyValuePair<int,int>(5,155) };
        MyChart.Series.Add(ls1);
        ls1.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None;        

    }
```

It doesn't work and here is the error:
'System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.LineSeries' does not contain a definition for 'MarkerStyle' and no extension method 'MarkerStyle' accepting a first argument of type '

Do I use a wrong .dll as the reference for charting? what is the right one?

Comment: Are you wrting for Winforms??

Comment: No, This is a WPF application.

Comment: You __always__ should __tag__ that!

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing System.Windows.Controls when you should be referencing System.Windows.Forms.

**In your project, right click "References" and add a reference to both: System.Windows.Forms and System.Windows.Form.DataVisualization**.

After referencing the right assemblies, change your code to look something like:

```
// Declare the following usings
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
...

    private void LoadLineChartData()
    {
        Chart myChart = new Chart();
        myChart.Series.Add("ls1");
        myChart.Series["ls1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        myChart.Series["ls1"].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None;

        KeyValuePair<int, int>[] pairs =
        {
            new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 100),
            new KeyValuePair<int, int>(2, 130),
            new KeyValuePair<int, int>(3, 150),
            new KeyValuePair<int, int>(4, 125),
            new KeyValuePair<int, int>(5, 155)
        };

        foreach (var pair in pairs)
            myChart.Series["ls1"].Points.AddXY(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Is this for Windows form application or it works foe WPF as well?